# apt-get hangs on download packages from our local repository

Tags: debian, apt, debian-squeeze

hope you guys can help me find out a solution to this problem that's causing me headache.

My company has a number of front end servers based upon Debian Squeeze, we also set up a local repository into the server lan for those packages that we need to backport or recompile for our own usage.

That's the problem, of all of the 14 front end servers there's only one that freezes during the packages download from the local repository.

I did every kind of test that popped into my brain:

Manually wget the package from shell: OK

Lynx browsing of the repository and download of a package: OK

Scp'ing a package from the repository: OK

Restarting apache on the repository server: Didn't helped me.

Tried to set the HTTP/1.1 pipelining to 0 into apt-get: Didn't helped.

Seems that the problem is only related to the apt-get, but how?

I really hope you guys have an idea, i'm thinking to schedule a server reboot, but it's a production machine so this is not so easy.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Did you try "apt-get clean"?

Comment: apt-get outputs something? you can try debug options on apt.conf

Comment: Danila, yes i did.

@tictacbum nothing but the normal output,hanging on "waiting for headers". Didn't found a suitable debug option though

Comment: can you paste the source.lst?

Comment: brigo i don't think the problem is into source.list, because i know that the server has some problem towards our local repository, but i can't figure it out, btw here it is http://pastebin.com/WiyS7Y5P

Comment: anything on sources.list.d? guess you already looked that...

Comment: yes i did, its empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing packets? It should give you some information on connection status, as this usually indicates network problems.

As an example, here's the output for a successfull package install:

Request:

> GET /ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sdl-image1.2/libsdl-image1.2_1.2.10-3_i386.deb HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: archive.ubuntu.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10)

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 13:53:57 GMT
>
> Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>
> Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Dec 2011 01:03:31 GMT
>
> ETag: "71c6-4b544cd24fec0"
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> Content-Length: 29126
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type: application/x-debian-package

Answer (score 0):

Is there a apt-cacher proxy declared in the Apt configuration?  Check, if the following file exists:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
```

See if it points to a server that can't be reached.  That would explain the timeout.  That happened to me, when I forgot I'd set it up.

Hope it helps.